Deferred CTD UST
Many people buy cash bonds which may be Off The Run (deliverable) but not Cheapest To Deliver vs short bond futures.
I've understood sometimes there's a Relative Value (RV) element to this in that someone may expect the cash to richen vs the future. One such reason is the expectation of this particular issue to become CTD in the next contract or the subsequent one etc.
By definition these issues will have a fairly large BNOC (Basis Net Of Carry) when not CTD, but if/when the bond becomes CTD the BNOC will be a lot smaller.
My questions:

I assume comparing the BNOC how I do across futures with different CTDs is not valid?
The expectation of PNL in this trade depends on the roll/carry and expected richening/cheapening of the currently non cheap cash vs the current CTD (proxy for future)?
Why would I not just trade the non cheap cash vs the cheap cash? Is it just due to liquidity of the future and to avoid repo issues etc?

Thanks
